# Cant send image in outlook when specifying image height and width using python

Tags: python, outlook

I am using a script from online that takes a screenshot of a excel sheet and then sends an email using that image in the body.
The script works fine until I specify image height and width in the html code for the email body.

```
import os
import win32com.client as client
from PIL import ImageGrab


workbook_path = r'C:\path\to\excel\excel.xlsx'

# start an instance of Excel
excel = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

# open the workbook
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbook_path)
# get the sheet 
sheet = wb.Worksheets['Sheet1']
excel.Visible = True
# copy the target range
copyrange= sheet.Range('A1:AA132')
copyrange.CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=2)

# grab the saved image from the clipboard and save to working directory
ImageGrab.grabclipboard().save('paste.png')
excel.Quit()

# get the path of the current working directory and create image path
image_path = 'paste.png'

html_body = """
     <div>
          <p>Hi All, </p>
            <p> text </p>
     </div>
     <div>
         <img src={} height = "500" width = "600"></img>
     </div>
 """

# # startup and instance of outlook
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

 # create a message
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)

 # set the message properties
message.To = 'to address'
message.Subject = 'subject '
message.HTMLBody = html_body.format(image_path)

# display the message to review
message.Display()
#message.Send()
```

in the email the text for the body appears but no image.
If I use `<img src={}></img>` the image appears

How can I change the size of the image for the email?

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a wild guess, but maybe something in the way the HTML is formatted is the issue? `<img>` is a self-closing tag, and generally you don't put spaces between the attr and the value.

Try this and see if it works:

```py
html_body = """
     <div>
          <p>Hi All, </p>
            <p> text </p>
     </div>
     <div>
         <img src={} height="500px" width="600px" />
     </div>
 """
```

Comment: hmm turns out the issue is because I didnt have the px but the px doesnt change the size
it works if i use % instead :(

Comment: That's definitely odd!